# Text Classification : Classifying N classes vs rest of the classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, multiclass-classification, text-classification

Apologies if this is naive, I am fairly new to the domain.
I have a requirement where I am trying to classify 2 types of text data, i.e, I have got 2 classes to classify my data upon. I am able to get acceptable results for them using word vectors, dimensionality reduction and then putting the data through to LinearSVC for classification. But my model is biased towards sentences with longer lengths. I know tfidf can help in this, but is there a way to apply that with word vectors, I dont want to lose its ability to predict on unseen similar data?

A follow up problem to this is, when there is data from some other class apart from the 2 classes that I have trained my data upon. I would like my model to be able to predict that the data doesn't belong to any of the 2 classes. Currently, it just predicts 1 of the 2 classes randomly.

I was thinking if I should first put my data through topic modelling, which would give an idea on what topic the text data is. Based on keywords from topic modelling, we can detect if my text data belongs to one of the 2 classes or not and then put it to my classification model for final prediction. But this doesn't seems very clean and I can see it failing as there's too much dependency on keywords generated by topic modelling. Is there any other finer and better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an **open-class** text classification problem, it's used in particular for some author identification problems.
I don't have any recent pointers but from a quick search I found this article: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N16-1061.pdf

In the field of author classification there is a similar problem called author verification, which can be treated as a [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) problem. You could consider using it in this way:

1. one-class classification between "known classes" vs. others
2. regular classification between the known classes

Comment: Thanks alot. That worked for me!

Comment: Can you please answer the first bit as well. How to neutralize bias in my model caused from length of input. Is it possible to somehow use tfidf alongwith word vectors ?

Comment: @AvneetSingh you didn't give any detail about how your vectors are built: one hot encoding? word frequency? Did you try any kind of normalization? You could indeed use TFIDF weights, but it's unlikely to help with the sentence length bias (there's no particular issue using TFIDF with unseen data btw). In general the problem of length bias is hard to completely solve, but sometimes it can be improved.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back. I have used spacy vectors to create vectors with 300 dimensions. I haven't tried any kind of normalization. My understanding is words in sentence are represented by numerical value in vectors, if I normalize vectors, that would end up changing the numerical values of vectors (and hence words too), isnt it?

Comment: @AvneetSingh it sounds like you're using words embeddings as vectors right? if yes this is not compatible with TFIDF or normalization indeed. In traditional vectors the values are usually the word frequency, so it makes sense to normalize or use weights. I'm not very skilled about word embeddings so I suggest you ask another question about this, it's better to focus on one point.

Comment: No worries, thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your desired two classes, relabel all other classes as a third class and then train your model on a three class classification problem.

Comment: Thank you, but that would just mean that I need to know what I am expecting in all the other cases. Which essentially is the problem. We don't know what data there can be in all the other cases.